# Why I can't get the variable in Ext.override?

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
(function(){
  var foo = "me";
  Ext.override(Ext.PagingToolbar, {
    initComponent : function(){
      console.debug(foo);
    }
  });
})();
```

but I can't get the foo's value in initComponent method, how?

Comment: That looks perfectly reasonable. What happens when you log it?

Answer (score 0):

1、I can get the foo's value in initComponent method，but you do not call it，code to write on ok

```
  (function(){
      var foo = "me";
      alert(foo);
      Ext.override(Ext.PagingToolbar, {
        initComponent : function(){
          console.debug(foo);
        }
      });
      var panel = new Ext.PagingToolbar();
      panel.initComponent();
    })();
```

Comment: You shouldn't call initComponent manually, it will be called by the component during construction.